# GRUB fails to install

Tags: boot, linux-mint, grub

For the past two days, I have been attempting to install Linux Mint 14 64-bit edition.

Each time, the ubiquity installer has failed with this error:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.

This is a fatal error
```

At this point, a dialog box pops up asking me if I want to install the bootloader on a different drive or partition, continue without installing a bootloader or cancel the installation. I have three HDDs installed in my box--one SSD disk with Windows 7 on it, and two for storage and this Linux installation--and I have tried to install the bootloader on each one with resulting in the same error.

The rest of the installation is intact and I can see that the filesystem and structure is correctly installed. So, I googled a bit and turned up some people suggesting [chroot into the installation and run grub-install from there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot). I did this and it returned an error message:

```
Path to `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.
```

Help me solve this, please!

Comment: What the model of motherboard you have?

Comment: Can you post your partiton layout and the output of `cat /boot/grub/device.map`?

Comment: @dchirikov GA-EP35-DS4

Comment: @user825518 That file does not exist. 

Actually, I have solved this particular problem. GRUB managed to install once I set the mount point for /boot to my ext2 boot partition in the ubiquity installer. 

So, now my problem is that I am dropping into initramfs shell because grub cannot locate / on the encrypted root partition. Here's pic of the error message I get: http://imgur.com/c8aWZ6c

Comment: Your question dosen't mention encryption (or type), your partition scheme, or file system types, if you can provide this information it would help :)

Comment: @arober11 here is partition scheme and lvm2 setup. http://pastebin.com/bRuYnjdy

I am not sure which the default encryption is for cryptsetup, but I followed this guide when I made the install: http://www.netzgewitter.com/2011/09/how-to-install-linux-mint-debian-edition-lmde-on-an-encrypted-hard-drive/

Comment: Are you aware that that how-to is from 2011? There is a more easy (and official) way to do so, [check this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1166).

Comment: @Braiam Thank you! I did not know that!