# LFS System not booting or GRUB cannot access /boot/grub on boot

Tags: linux, grub, lfs

The closest question I could find is this one, however it is still quite a bit different from what I am needing: [GRUB fails to install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62295/grub-fails-to-install)

**My specific setup and the steps I followed to produce this**

I am attempting to build the Linux From Scratch project, using book version 7.2. I have followed every step up along the way, and performed every test that I could do to make sure that everything was operating correctly after building. The largest change I had to make was the partitioning, I have /dev/sda1 (as /), /dev/sda2 (as /home), /dev/sda3 (as swap), and /dev/sdb1 (as /source for compiling).

I am performing the installation on a blank hard drive inside of VirtualBox using a LiveCD as the host OS. So, I have ran into very few problems up until the very end. For compiling the kernel, it is not very specific for what options I need to select, so I selected the default options with one change, I made sure the option in "Device Drivers ---> Generic Driver Options ---> Maintain a devtmpfs filesystem to mount at /dev" was checked.

After following the rest of the instructions on setting up GRUB, after the reboot the boot process freezes with the following output visible:

```
ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata3.00: ATA-6: VBOX HARDDISK, 1.0, max UDMA/133
ata3.00: 33554432 sectors, multi 128: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA VBOX HARDDISK 1.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 4:0:0:0: CD-ROM VBOX CD-ROM 1.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
List of all partitions:
No filesystem could mount root, tried:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.5.2 #1
Call Trace:
 ? panic
 ? mount_block_root
 ? xen_write_msr_safe
 ? mount_root
 ? prepare_namespace
 ? kernel_init
 ? start_kernel
 ? kernel_thread_helper
atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
```

So, when I first received that, I thought that maybe it was something to do with the kernel, maybe I didn't select what I had to select, and after a bit of googling, I found out that I should make sure that "SATA_SIL" is enabled. I also found a website detailing the kernel options that need to be enabled for a kernel running in VirtualBox (http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Virtualbox_Guest). I then restored my machine to the saved state right before I compiled the kernel and recompiled it with the options specified on that website, along with SATA_SIL.

However, after the long compilation of the kernel, I went along with the book and issued the command `grub-install /dev/sda`. However, this time, rather than installing, GRUB returned the following error:

```
Path to `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.
```

My first thought was that it had something to do with file permissions (because "is not readable" really sounds like file permissions). So, just to see, I set the /boot folder (recursively) to 777. Still no success. After that, I did some googling, but really returned no meaningful results.

So, following along with that, I restored the machine to the version where GRUB was working but wouldn't boot up, used the same configuration and recompiled the kernel there (which, I had to add a new hard drive, /dev/sdc, because there wasn't enough space in /dev/sdb1 to compile the kernel with the new options). After going through the long compilation again, I installed the kernel, rebooted, and ... same error dump as before.

**The main question**

So, now I am to the point where I think I may need some help, if anyone has any ideas how I may get past this boot error and/or the GRUB installation path error, that would be great!

**Extra information**

All of my software is the exact version from the LFS version 7.2, a full list may be found here: http://pastebin.com/TiJBhbce

Here is a complete list of the structure and setup of all of the drives in the computer:
    root:~# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xeeeb9d91

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     6293503     3145728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         6293504     6817791      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         6817792     8388607      785408   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes
171 heads, 2 sectors/track, 98112 cylinders, total 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4c41c1df

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    33554431    16776192   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
43 heads, 32 sectors/track, 6096 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd3de256f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     8388607     4193280   83  Linux
```

And the drive that should start as / upon reboot, here's the contents of /dev/sda1:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 Feb 17 20:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    60 Feb 17 22:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 17 13:11 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 17 16:00 boot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 17 20:46 build
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:06 dev
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 Feb 17 15:52 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 13:11 home
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Feb 17 22:11 lib
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Feb 16 13:09 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:24 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:24 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:24 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:06 proc
drwxr-x---  3 root root  4096 Feb 17 22:14 root
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 17 09:38 run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 17 14:36 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 13:11 sources
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:24 srv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:06 sys
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root 20480 Feb 17 22:12 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 Feb 16 18:51 tools
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Feb 16 20:24 usr
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Feb 16 23:26 var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to complete LFS, I believe the reason that GRUB was giving the specified error was because I didn't have everything mounted correctly. This script should mount everything as needed:

```
export LFS=/mnt/lfs
mkdir -p $LFS
mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sda1 $LFS
mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sda2 $LFS/home
mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 $LFS/sources
/sbin/swapon -v /dev/sda3
mount -v -t tmpfs -o size=20m tmpfs /tmp
mount -v --bind /dev $LFS/dev
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/proc
mount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
chroot "$LFS" /tools/bin/env -i \
    HOME=/root                  \
    TERM="$TERM"                \
    PS1='\u:\w\$ '              \
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin \
    /tools/bin/bash --login +h
```

As for the error about not being able to boot up, that was being caused by the kernel compiling. I was using ext4 for my hard drives, and I have to compile that into the kernel in order for it to work. Here is the kernel setup I had to use:

```
Device Drivers  --->
    Generic Driver Options -->
        [*] Maintain a devtmpfs filesystem to mount at /dev
File systems  --->
    <*> The Extended 4 (ext4) filesystem
        [*] Use ext4 for ext2/ext3 file systems
        [*] Ext4 extended attributes
            [*] Ext4 POSIX Access Control Lists
            [*] Ext4 Security Labels
```